# How can I use the Youtube API to post only text and images in the community menu?

Tags: youtube-api

How can I use the Youtube API to post only text and images in the community menu?

like this image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veYqI.png)

I tried to look in https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3
But it only has video.

I hope there's a way. Or someone who can help me do it Or please tell me it doesn't have an API to support it

Comment: As far as I know there is no such API.